# Tag convention for other eosio-based blockchain networks?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Seeing as there are a few eosio-based blockchain networks (and likely more to come), should we handle these network-specific questions via a tag identifying the specific network/chain? I assume such questions are appropriate & relevant.

Comment: Fantastic question, 

I suppose so yes, the stack exchange is EOSIO which represents the software, not the main chain.

Given the different characteristics of each chain, it makes sense to have different tags to filter. 

Should we implement this system, however, what's the likelihood of askers knowing to add such a tag?

Comment: @JohnWilliamson Developers new to SE may not know. In these cases, if it's obvious to moderators, reviewers or other users, they could create/add tag to the posts as they come across them.

Comment: Yeah makes sense! Will wait and see what others think on the idea.

Answer (score 1):

How about prefixing such tags with something like `side-chain-CHAIN_NAME`, or `sc-NAME`. For example `sc-telos` or `side-chain-telos`. I think that the term side chain should be included somehow, as there will definitely be side chains going forward that have names matching existing tag terms. I would recommend using `sc` because this could refer to `side-chain` or `sister-chain`.